# Two Way Binding on Multi-select WinForms Listbox?

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, listbox, multi-select

I have a project where we are loading a multi-select listbox from a collection of objects.
I have another entity object that has a collection that I want to bind to SelectedItems somehow.

Is there any way to do this using object binding sources or some kind of binding source without writing code?  Sure I can loop through the collection and get the selected items but I'd prefer to do it more cleanly with windows data-binding.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't bind the SelectedItems (or CheckedItems in CheckedListBox)... I can't tell how many times I wished it were possible !