# Binding to Winforms Listbox or DevExpress ListBoxControl (SelectionMode=MultiExtended)

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, listbox, devexpress

I have a class, that contains various attributes and list of related objects.
I am making a form to input/edit instances of the class. I am databinding attributes of the object (class instance) to the controls of the input/edit form.

Everything works fine except that i can not find a way to bind related object list to a listbox (with SelectionMode MultiExtended selected). Listbox control should contain all possible values and selected those values, that are in the list of related objects.

### For example

Lets say I have a class "Client" that has related objects "Products" (that would be a list of products that this specific client is buying from me)
When I edit Client record in a form, i need that the listbox (or devexpress listboxcontrol) "Products" contains all the products that i can supply, and selected only those products this Client is buying.

How can I accomplish this task using databinding?

P.S. I have found an old topic, that it was not possible to bind to listbox with multi-selection... is it still not possible? Maybe you can suggest to do it differently?

[Two Way Binding on Multi-select WinForms Listbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1233317/two-way-binding-on-multi-select-winforms-listbox)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SelectedItems` property of the DevEx `ListBoxControl` is read only so you are not able to bind your collection to it. So, the short answer is **No, you still can't use data binding in this situation**.  You can still data bind your list of all Products to populate the `ListBoxControl`, but because you are using multiple selection and because you can not data bind the selected items I would recommend against it.

Instead, just for this listbox, I would do things completely without data binding. For example to populate your control:

```
// populate the listbox with a list of all Products
// allProducts is an IEnumerable<Product> where Product has a Description property
listBoxControl1.Items.AddRange(allProducts.Select(x => x.Description).ToArray());
```

Then, to make your selections found in your Client class:

```
// "client" is type Client which contains a collection of selected Products
foreach (var product in client.Products)
{
    var idx = listBoxControl1.FindStringExact(product.Description);
    listBoxControl1.SetSelected(idx, true);
}
```

Then, when it is time to save, clear out the Products collection in your Client object and then use the `ListBoxControl.SelectedItems` property to repopulate it.